# importing modules selectively in python (django)

Tags: python, django, module

Suppose I have multiple const files which has constant values in it.

```
const/
      const_1.py
      MAX = 10

      const_2.py
      MAX = 100
```

Then I have 3 python packages (or django apps)

```
common_app/
def sum():
    result = 0;
    for i in range(const.MAX):
        result += i
    return i

app_1/
# somehow let common_app to use const_1.py when he's using const                                                                                                                                                                                                            
assert(common_app.sum() == 55)

app_2/
# somehow let common_app to use const_2.py when he's using const                                                                                                                                                                                                            
assert(common_app.sum() == 5050)
```

So, when a module imports another module, I want the imported module to selectively import another module.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, i dont undestand, show me a code example

Comment: Cant you just do `from const.const_1 import MAX` and `from const.const_2 import MAX` in each app ?

Comment: There are many more than just MAX constants, and I don't want to modify all common_app/app_1/app_2 to pass different arguments. I want to pass the const module itself (ideally) for common_app to load. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `from const import conts_1` ?

Comment: Can I pass that consts_1 to common_app somehow so that common_app uses consts_1 when it refers 'const' in its code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to import dynamically.

```
from importlib import import_module

# modify it to suit your case
statement = True

if statement:
    const = import_module('const_1')
else:
    const = import_module('const_2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, very close, but would it be possible for the client code (app_1, app_2) to decide which module common_app to use?